# Is it possible to export data from Android Studio Network Inspector (Electric Eel or later)

Tags: android, android-studio, networking, har

I am using Android Studio Electric Eel 2022.1.1 Patch 2, and I want to export the data from Network Inspector as a HAR file for analysis.

I've searched online quite a bit and scoured the Android Studio UI and haven't found anything. I'm guessing it is not possible from the IDE.

Does anyone know of a way to export the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible right now. I tested until Giraffe where there is at least an improvement of adding rules to network inspector to modify responses for example but there is still no export feature unfortunately. It's not mentioned in the Hedgehog (beta) and Iguana (canary) [feature list](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features) either.

If you don't want to use Charles then probably you might want to take a look at the [Chucker](https://github.com/ChuckerTeam/chucker) library which acts as an OkHttp interceptor and can export to HAR file.